# It is possible an synchronous mysql query in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I try find solutions like "Promices" or modules like "synchronize" or "sync", but I donsen't fine a properly solution ):

The way its I have like 10 tables 'user', 'data', 'game'. And functions like:

```
getUsers(){}       // UserTable
getData(){}        // DataModel
getGames(){}       // GameTable
getUserByGames(){} // UserModel
```

And some funtions have needs to return me a model or table... and in some cases I need that model or that 'answer' to make another query and another stuff.

So, i need to do synchronous querys to make that in the best way, no use '.then' or stuff like that :/

Did you know how I can doit in nodejs?

(Maybe a solution can be put a flag in true each async function and in the callback change the flag to false. With a while for dosent end the original function?)

Comment: You should really take a look at waterfall method on async module, it will solve your problem. Once I had a similar problem like yours, with waterfall I was able to easily solve it. Check: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall.

Comment: No, you can't make sync queries as far as i know. This would also be very bad style as every query would block your node process. If you want to use node you better make sure to understand and use async operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix callbacks, sequential and parallel execution, loops, recursion with [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS). Here is an example to illustrate:

```
var SynJS = require('synjs');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'tracker',
  password : 'tracker123',
  database : 'tracker'
});

function runSQLQuery(modules,connection,context,query,queryParams) {
    var res = {done: false};
    connection.query(query,queryParams, function(err, rows, fields) {
          res.err = err;
          res.rows = rows;
          res.done = true;
          //console.log('got rows:',rows);
          modules.SynJS.resume(context);
    });
    return res;
}

function myFunc(modules,connection) {
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        console.log('Iteration:',i);
        // sequential execution
        var res1 = modules.runSQLQuery(modules,connection,_synjsContext,"SELECT 100+? as id",[i]);
        SynJS.wait(res1.done);
        console.log("res1=", res1.rows);

        var res2 = modules.runSQLQuery(modules,connection,_synjsContext,"SELECT 200+? as id",[i]);
        SynJS.wait(res2.done);
        console.log("res2=", res2.rows);

        // parallel execution
        var res3 = modules.runSQLQuery(modules,connection,_synjsContext,"SELECT 300+? as id",[i]);
        var res4 = modules.runSQLQuery(modules,connection,_synjsContext,"SELECT 400+? as id",[i]);
        SynJS.wait(res3.done && res4.done);
        console.log("res3,4=", res3.rows, res4.rows);
    }
};

var modules = {
        SynJS:  SynJS,
        mysql:  mysql,
        runSQLQuery: runSQLQuery,
};

SynJS.run(myFunc,null,modules,connection,function () {
    console.log('done');
    connection.end();
});
```

It produces following output:

```
Iteration: 0
res1= [ { id: 100 } ]
res2= [ { id: 200 } ]
res3,4= [ { id: 300 } ] [ { id: 400 } ]
Iteration: 1
res1= [ { id: 101 } ]
res2= [ { id: 201 } ]
res3,4= [ { id: 301 } ] [ { id: 401 } ]
Iteration: 2
res1= [ { id: 102 } ]
res2= [ { id: 202 } ]
res3,4= [ { id: 302 } ] [ { id: 402 } ]
done
```