# join all async calls to return some result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

What will be the performant solution for this problem where I want to make some async calls, wait in last until all the calls are completed, then return the result.

```
function parseAndMatch(arg1, arg2){
   async.all([
      asyncCall1(arg1, arg2),
      asyncCall2(arg1, arg2)]
   ).then( result => {
      //do something with result;
      return finalResult;
   });
}
```

I tried to fit npm `deasync`, `asyncawait`, `bluebird`, and `async` packages to solve this problem. But I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: well... the `then return the result.` part is pretty much impossible. Otherwise,  the answer is yes.

Comment: possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Comment: @KevinB I found that question. But as it was for frontend, and I was trying to implement this in nodejs server side application, I thought to ask separately.

Comment: Teh concept is the same for both ends, javascript is javascript

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41540117/1464130 it provides an example on parallel or sequential async calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of @wing answer's I solved this problem using native `Promise` and npm `deasync` library. But I'm not sure how efficient and performant it is.

```
function parseAndMatch(callback) {
  return Promise.all([
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var sum = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                sum++;
            }
            return resolve(sum);
      }),
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var sum = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 90000; i++) {
                sum++;
            }
            return resolve(sum);
      }),
  ]);
}

function joinAndReturn(){
    var done = false;
    var result;
    parseAndMatch().then((results) => {
        result = results[0] + results[1];
        done = true;
    });
    deasync.loopWhile(function(){return !done;});
    return result;
}

console.log(joinAndReturn());//100002
```

Comment: The reason I used Promise in `parseAndMathc` function, because some parallel functions can be async.

Comment: Are you using `deasync.loopWhile` to pause the `joinAndReturn` function until `parseAndMatch` has resolved? If you are native JavaScript can handle this – see [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: may be using that can improve the performance. Right now I'm trying to use callbacks or other alternatives. Because above code can impact the performance badly.

Comment: Although I found some alternate ways to code where I'm not falling in this situation, I'm marking this is an answer until some good answer is given.

Comment: Does my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41901356/3050293) or my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900886/join-all-async-calls-to-return-some-result/41901356#comment71012158_41901919) regarding [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) not resolve your issue? If they don't please share more details on what trouble you are having. If they do, at least upvote answers that have helped you.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript multiple asynchronous operations can be handled by using `all` method on the `Promise` object. This **does not** require the use of libraries.

`Promise.all` returns a Promise and takes an iterable containing multiple Promises that require resolution. Once **all** Promises in the iterable have resolved the Promise returned by calling `Promise.all` resolves. If **any** Promise in the iterable rejects, the Promise returned by `Promise.all` immediately rejects.

`Promise.all` resolves with an iterable of all the resolution values of the Promises given to it. `Promise.all` rejects with the value of the Promise given in the iterable that rejected.

Taking your example, you would use `Promise.all` like this:

```
function parseAndMatch(arg1, arg2){
  return Promise.all([
    asyncCall1(arg1, arg2),
    asyncCall2(arg1, arg2),
  ]);
}

parseAndMatch()
  .then(doSomethingElse)
  .catch(handleRejection);
```

**Further reading**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all

Answer (score -1):

If `asyncCall1` and `asyncCall2` return Promises. Using [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html):

```
function parseAndMatch(arg1, arg2){
  return Promise.join(
      asyncCall1(arg1, arg2), 
      asyncCall2(arg1, arg2), 
      (result1, result2) => {
        //do something with result1, result2;
        return finalResult;
  });
}
```

If they support callback. Using [async.parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel):

```
function parseAndMatch(arg1, arg2, callback) {
  async.parallel([
      callback => {
        asyncCall1(arg1, arg2, callback);
      },
      callback => {
        asyncCall2(arg1, arg2, callback);
      },
    ], (err, results) => {
        if (err)
          return callback(err);
        //do something with result[0], result[1];
        return callback(null, results);
    })
}
```

Comment: You can also use the standard `Promise.all()`